# Using ReadList to import specific arrays of a multi-dimensional variable

Tags: import, files-and-directories, list-manipulation

Consider a large numerical variable (almost 1GB) which was constructed like below:

```
output={scalar1,{Matrix1,Matrix2,Matrix3,scalar2}};
```

I used `Export` to save `output` variable as a .csv file. Now I want to import specific array of `output` variable to notebook, say row 1 of `Matrix1`, and do some post-processing operations. Clearly, `Import` command is not an effective and  applicable choice due to high time & memory usage. Hence, one may use `OpenRead` and then `ReadList` to read desired arrays. The question is, how I can implement `ReadList` to import specific array of a multi-dimensional variable. Here is a simple example of `output`:

```
output = {0.049003,
{{{0, 0., -1.97949}, {0, 5., 9.01025}},
{{0, -1.97949, -6.53072}, {10, 9.01025, 5.13141}},
{{0, -7.91796, -10.287}, {0, -3.95898, -11.5564}},
0.048003}};
```

and the corresponding .csv file:

0.049003
"{{0, 0., -1.9794901687515782}, {0, 5., 9.01025491562421}}","{{0, -1.9794901687515782, -6.530723746803215}, {10, 9.01025491562421, 5.131408741303968}}","{{0, -7.917960675006313, -10.286973637200234}, {0, -3.9589803375031565, -11.556404359777813}}",0.048003

Comment: Notice that the records in the CSV file are saved as strings due to the ragged structure of your array. This will make the recovery of your data slow, and possibly complicated. I would suggest saving to a different file format instead. If you don't need to share the datafiles across different computer platforms, you could also look at saving your data in a proprietary binary format using `DumpSave`.

Comment: @MarcoB for my purpose, `DumpSave` is not an option because of the fact that you've mentioned. it's not portable between different architectures. Moreover, I don't need to load the entire context.

Comment: I don't understand why you absolutely want to export your output in that particular list of lists form if, anyway, you just want later to import only specific parts of it. Have you considered just to create separate files (with specific clear names) for each specific expression, then import them directly: i mean for example `output[[2,1]]>>"matrix1.m"` then importing it with `<<"matrix1.m"`.

Comment: @SquareOne I cannot reproduce `output`. it is the result of a long time evaluation on a high-performance computing system. But your idea seems simple and interesting. I'll consider your suggestion in my next evaluations. However, `Matrix1` itself may contain a large amount of data.

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, somehow I have found my solution. I developed a module for this purpose. But since I'm a beginner in Mathematica,  the algorithm may seem elementary.  Here it is:

```
GetArray[fName_, rowIndex_, matIndex_] := 
Module[{fileName = fName, matID = matIndex, row = rowIndex, stream, 
tempArray, mat, outputList},

stream = OpenRead[StringJoin[NotebookDirectory[], fileName]];
tempArray = 
ReadList[stream, Record, 3, RecordSeparators -> {{"{{"}, {"}}"}}];
Close[stream];
mat = ToString[tempArray[[matIndex]]];
Clear[tempArray];
mat = StringSplit[mat, "}, {"];
outputList = 
StringSplit[
StringReplace[
mat[[row]], {"}" -> "", "{" -> "", WhitespaceCharacter -> ""}], 
 ","];
Return[ToExpression[outputList]];
];
```

for a 511mb csv file, in order to extract fourth row of `Matrix1`:

```
GetArray["myFile.csv", 4, 1] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Utilizing this module, It took `23.460668` seconds to process the file on a 4GB Ram with Intel Core i5-2410M CPU, while it's almost impossible to load `myFile.csv` using `Import` on this machine.